# How to declare a variable in gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I wan to declare a variable inside android `gradle` file of type boolean 
that variable should be `true` when I run unit test case and `false` when I run application. any suggestion? I don't want to use Java variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
buildTypes {
    unittest {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "UNIT_TEST", "true"
    }
    run {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "UNIT_TEST", "false"
    }
}
```

---

**or**

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "boolean", "UNIT_TEST", "false" //Change this value accordingly.
}
```

Comment: It is right. But do you need this variable only to disable Crashlytics?

Comment: This is default. now how to make it false when I run application. if I am not doing unit testing

Comment: by **run** do you mean the signed build installed from play store?

Comment: I mean I have written Unit test cases. When I run that class UNIT_TEST should be true but when I run application on device UNIT_TEST should be false

Comment: on simple saying I want to ignore some line while doing unit testing in code. So I wannt to declare a variable inside gradle so that I can check and skip perticular line

Comment: you can create product flavors like unittest and run like we have release and debug in gradle file there you can define different value in those

Comment: is this possible without using Gradle or I need to use Java static variable ?

Comment: Check the update answer. You can also work with a static variable, but declare that static variable in your application class

Comment: You are saying to create another build varient for Unit testing. Is is not possible to work in same build variant and make it false when test case are running ?

Comment: Ya possible. But make sure you change it's value when you want to run or creating build to upload on the play store

Comment: If so there is always one boolean flag which differentiates debug and release. **_BuildConfig.DEBUG_**. You can also use that if it helps you.

Comment: Brijesh Just one clarification I want to use same varient. I dont want to differenciate between debug and release. because that code should run in debug mode also. only when I run test case that line should be ignored.

Comment: is this possible with gradle ?

Comment: Yes possible. instead of two variants just declare variable in the defaultConfig of your gradle, as i suggested. but than you have to make sure to change it's value.

Comment: ok got it. we have to change it manually every time. there is no way to identify that test case are runing not application

Comment: Yes. Updated that in the answer